# OSPP.VBS cmd prompt

Tags: microsoft-office, cmd.exe, microsoft-office-2013

I am running into a problem with running the following command in cmd to retrieve the last 5 digits of my Office key.

The command prompt is as follows:

```
cscript “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS” /dstatus
```

Opening CMD, I changed the directory to the root of `C:\` and ran the command, but I get the following error:

```
"Input Error: There is no file extension in "C:\"C:\program"."
```

I verified the file is there in the program files x86 folder, so I am not sure where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Replace the smart quotes `“` and `”` with normal quotes `"`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I will try that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hi McDonald's thanks for taking the time to respond. I think I got that issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd as administrator

type cd C:\Program Files/Microsoft Office/Office16

hit enter

then you want to type ospp.vbs /dstatus

done